# Implementing flurry analytics in android

Tags: android, flurry, cocos2d-x-2.x, flurry-analytics

I am trying to integrate flurry analytics in game which is written in cocos2dx and i am testing for android. I have just written initing code in `onCreate` method and i am getting following error in LogCat:

> 03-10 15:03:11.890: E/dalvikvm(29821): Could not find class
>   **'com.flurry.sdk.i', referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.hu.a**

Comment: Try those steps : Properties > Java build path > Order and export > Mark your jar > Move jar to top of the list.

Comment: @Skizo i tried but no luck!

Comment: I have the same problem, tried marking the jar, unmarking, removing it and adding it again, nothing helps.

Comment: Do you have Proguard enabled?

Comment: @user3285373, also does it cause a crash in your application or do you see it as just a warning in logcat?